# 400 Bad Request C# Microsoft Face Api

Tags: c#, httprequest

I am trying to get simple functionality from the Microsoft Face API, using this example provided ([link](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236)):

```
// Request headers
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{subscription key}");

// Request parameters
queryString["returnFaceId"] = "true";
queryString["returnFaceLandmarks"] = "false";
queryString["returnFaceAttributes"] = "{string}";
var uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?" + queryString;

HttpResponseMessage response;

// Request body
byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{body}");

using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
{
   content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("< your content type, i.e. application/json >");
   response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
}
```

Whenever I execute the code, I get a 400 bad request, of which I cannot how to view the specific cause. This is how mine looks:

```
// Request headers
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

// Request parameters
queryString["returnFaceId"] = "true";
queryString["returnFaceLandmarks"] = "false";
queryString["returnFaceAttributes"] = "Age";
var uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?" + queryString;

HttpResponseMessage response;

// Request body
byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"url\":\"http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/272/907/dc1.jpg/ \"}");

using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
{
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
    Console.Write(response.StatusCode);
}
```

Comment: Well you do have a trailing `/` on your URL which probably doesn't help as it means your image is not getting returned.

Comment: Thank you David for the resolution. The extra slash at the end of the url was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine and the only issue I see is that your image is not accessible. I am getting access denied error, if I try to access the image directly via browser. Is that something you have checked?

I tried the below code and it works fine:

var client = new HttpClient();
                var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

```
            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","please use your key");

            // Request parameters
            queryString["returnFaceId"] = "true";
            queryString["returnFaceLandmarks"] = "false";
            queryString["returnFaceAttributes"] = "age";
            var uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?" + queryString;

            HttpResponseMessage response;

            // Request body
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"url\":\"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-AI__M0nZDU4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGs/P5tdI3rFaFs/s0-c-k-no-ns/photo.jpg \"}");


            using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
            {
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                Console.Write(response.StatusCode);

            }
```

Comment: I said this in a comment 20 minutees ago, why did you feel like an answer was needed?

Comment: Apologies David I did not see your reply at 0.18, and all I did was typing my reply (it took a while for me to finish). Yours is the precise answer!!